# Font used to display specific characters in gnome-terminal

Tags: fonts, gnome-terminal, unicode, fontconfig

I want to find out which font (i.e. the .ttf or .otf file name) is used for displaying a specific unicode character in my gnome-terminal (in order to setup my editor to use the same fonts). How can this be done?

I hope that this could be done e.g. via fontconfig. But I don't know the terminal handles character: Does it call fontconfig for each unicode character to find a or the best matching font?

Comment: currently not on ubuntu machine, so can't write a perfect answer. But as far as I remember,  gnome-terminal font can be changed from gnome-terminal setting itself (obviously if you are using gui mode)

Comment: @g_p Thanks for the hint. But this only shows a the default selected font. If the char is not found it seems some fallback is applied to find another font. I want to understand how this is done in order to manually find that fallback font.